# How to avoid the "too deeply nested" error when creating PDFs with Sphinx?

Tags: python, latex, pdf-generation, python-sphinx

I have a fairly complex project with a fairly large documentation.
Converting the normal *user guide* to PDF with Sphinx via `make latexpdf` works quite well. However, if I also want to include the library reference with all function, class, and module documentations, the command fails with:

```
! LaTeX Error: Too deeply nested.
```

Manually reducing the nesting is not an option. Sphinx internally nests parameter descriptions, function descriptions, module descriptions and whatnot. So figuring out in each case how to reduce the nesting is almost impossible.

Comment: ` latex_elements = {   'maxlistdepth' : '20',` works for me.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I solved the problem by adding some latex statements to the sphinx preamble.
Accordingly, I created a new `latex_preamble.tex` file in my sphinx *source* folder. It contains only the following two commands:

```
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlistdepth{99}
```

Moreover, In the `conf.py` file, also within my *source* folder, I changed the following (you can lookout for the `latex_elements` variable in the `conf.py` file, it is usually commented out):

```
fh = open('latex_preamble.tex', 'r+')
PREAMBLE = fh.read()
fh.close()
latex_elements = {
# Additional stuff for the LaTeX preamble.
'preamble': PREAMBLE,
}
```

Hence, now sphinx uses the `enumitem` package that allows arbitrary nesting. I guess nowadays `enumitem` should be part of any latex distribution. I did not need to install the package. Moreover, this also worked out of the box on [read the docs](https://readthedocs.org/).

Comment: I found that that I could achieve the same result by just entering the commands directly into the conf.py file, thus: `'preamble': r'\usepackage{enumitem}\setlistdepth{99}'`