# Sphinx: "Too deeply nested" when building PDF from source

Tags: python, latex, boto, python-sphinx, restructuredtext

I am trying to build the `boto` documentation from the source RST files in the [`boto` repo](https://github.com/boto/boto).

However, a `build latex` from the `docs` folder of the source leads to a:

```
! LaTeX Error: Too deeply nested.
```

How can I fix this? Or alternatively, is there a way to get at the built PDFs on the [readthedocs page](https://boto.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to avoid the "too deeply nested" error when creating PDFs with Sphinx?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28454217/how-to-avoid-the-too-deeply-nested-error-when-creating-pdfs-with-sphinx)

Comment: @Rudi I agree, I cannot remove the question since it has an upvoted answer, but please feel free to vote as a duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download the PDF for any documentation on readthedocs.org by selecting the little button in the lower-right corner of the page labeled `v: latest`.  You should see a pop-up menu and one of the choices is to download the PDF.

Comment: Did not know that -- thank you. I will wait to see if anyone is able to answer the code error part of the question. If not, will mark yours as accepted.